# Struggling writing my first joins query

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables that I have tried to lay out below.  I am beyond stuck.  I haven't done a lot of queries, never done joins before and I am really confused how do this.  An example query I would have would be in plain english,

> get all portfolio_item_ids from skill_area where web_design="1", 
>       then get all the rows from portfolio_items with the id values of the portfolio_item_ids 
>       then for each row, get the row from tags where portfolio_item_id is equal to portfolio_item_id and the value of one of illustrator, photoshop or css is 1.

QUERY I managed to come up with

---

**SELECT** portfolio_item_id

**FROM** skill_area s

**WHERE** web_design=1

---

**SELECT** *

**FROM** portfolio_items p

**WHERE** p.id= s.portfolio_item_id

---

**SELECT** *

**FROM** tags t

**WHERE** s.portfolio_item_id=t.portfolio_item_id

---

so I think this is right and I just have to join it together now

---

**Portfolio Items**

id

item_name

description

**Skill Area**

portfolio_item_id

web design

branding

print

**Tags**

portfolio_item_id

illustrator

photoshop

css

Comment: You should change the part 'and the value = 1' because that is confusing. Try 'and the value of one of illustrator, photoshop or css is 1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it down in steps, like you have in your 'plain english' statement:

1. get web_design skill_area's

   ```
   select * from skill_area where web_design = '1'
   ```
2. join with portfolio_items

   ```
   select * 
    from skill_area s, portfolio_items p 
    where web_design = '1' 
      and p.id = s.portfolio_item_id
   ```
3. join with tags, selecting row where value=1 and returning just the columns from the tags table)

   ```
   select t.* 
    from skill_area s, portfolio_items p, tags t 
    where web_design = '1' 
      and p.id = s.portfolio_item_id
      and p.id = t.portfolio_item_id
      and t.value = '1'
   ```

Comment: I'm just reading through this trying to follow, step by step instructions makes it much simpler! I take it the letters are abbrevs of the tables?  In number 3, it starts select t., well t hasn't been defined anywhere so how does it know what it is?

Comment: yes, the letters are abbreviations (they're called aliases). Look a little closer... 't' is an alias for 'tags'.

Comment: oh I see so it can be defined further down the query?  I thought it went in order it was stated.

Comment: @VinodKurup ahh oh ive got it to almost the end, the issue now is I confused people by saying value =1, what I meant to say was:   retrieve all the column names whose field contains 1 for that portfolio_item_id

Comment: Hmmm... it's not so easy to get column 'names' (as opposed to values) with simple DB queries. Either use something like @AngeloNeuschitzer's answer, or do that step after you get the query results.

Comment: @VinodKurup ok no worries thanks for making it clearer.  I'm a little better on understanding it, but not much..I'll edit my code above to show what I have figured out so far

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT sa.portfolio_item_id, pi.*, subtags.*
FROM skill_area sa
INNER JOIN portfolio_items pi ON sa.portfolio_item_id = pi.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT CASE WHEN illustrator = '1' THEN 'illustrator' 
                        WHEN photoshop = '1' THEN 'photoshop' 
                        ELSE 'css' END as tag, portfolio_item_id 
            FROM tags) subtags ON sa.portfolio_item_id = subtags.portfolio_item_id
WHERE sa.web_design = '1'
```

You commented you want to have an alternative where you just get all the columns from tags.

```
SELECT sa.portfolio_item_id, pi.*, tags.*
FROM skill_area sa
INNER JOIN portfolio_items pi ON sa.portfolio_item_id = pi.id
INNER JOIN tags ON sa.portfolio_item_id = tags.portfolio_item_id
WHERE sa.web_design = '1'
```

Comment: thank you!  I should also mention that I need to be able to get column name where the tags value is 1, will the corresponding result contain the details of the column name?

Comment: I see, so you don't want the three columns (having values 0,0,1) but have the name of the column... Just a second I'll fix it in.

Comment: no I want the column name where the value ="1" as part of the result

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't work so easily. You can use a CASE WHEN structure (one way or the other, the way I designed it is not the 'best') to solve that.

Comment: @Nicola I'm unsure about how your actual data looks like, so maybe you get the right results when using a `LEFT JOIN` for the subtags. Or, if you have entries in tags where there are no columns with a '1' in them, you need to add ` WHERE illustrator = '1' OR photoshop = '1' OR css = '1'` after `FROM tags`

Comment: you see the issue is I have loads of tags, so it would be a long query going through them all.  DO you think I've structured my database the right way?

Comment: That depends on your rdbms. If you can create pivoted tables in it then you can use that (try for yourself and ask a new question for that). If not, then you have created your database wrong (in classical database design you have done it wrong anyway). You should use tag ids and a tag table that connects that ids to names.

Comment: ahh tag ids and a tag table, how does that work?  My portfolio items will have multiple tags so I couldn't think of another way to do it.

Comment: @Nicola You should get a teacher. You can write me an email and if I have time I'll answer a question or two. The keyword for your current situation is `n->m relation` or `Many to Many`. Good luck, but please accept an answer (I'd suggest @Vinods) as it has solved your initial question.

Comment: Thanks.  I had one in 2nd year of university but didn't understand databases whatsoever then!  I'll maybe leave out my tag thing just now.  I'd like to email you to ask you how you would advise setting the tables up then, thanks.

Comment: hey could I ask you one more tiny little thing?  Could you edit the code to show me how to just get all the columns for a matched row in the tags table?  What I'll then do is loop through them using php and checking if they have a value of 1 if so, echoing out the column name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      P.*
FROM        SkillArea S
INNER JOIN  Portfolio P ON S.portfolio_item_id = P.id
INNER JOIN  Tags T ON T.portfolio_item_id = P.id
WHERE       S.web_design = 1
AND         P.id = 1
```

Comment: He didn't want everything from S

Comment: thank you!  I should also mention that I need to be able to get column name where the tags value is 1, will the corresponding result contain the details of the column name?

Comment: Does the `Tags` table have an id field?

Comment: no i didnt think it needed one, just the id of the portfolio_item

Answer (score 0):

Here is what such a query could look like. I tried to translate from your english variation verbatim to help your understanding, and included annotations to describe the stpes.

```
select s.portfolio_item_id, p.*, t.*
from Skill_Area s                                 -- get all portfolio_item_ids from skill_area
inner join Portfolio_Items p on                   -- then get all the rows from portfolio_items
    p.portfolio_item_ids = s.portfolio_item_ids   -- with the id values of portfolio_item_ids
inner join Tags t on                              -- then for each row, get the row from tags
    t.portfolio_item_id = p.portfolio_item_id     -- where portfolio_item_id is equal to portfolio_item_id
    and t.portfolio_item_id = 1                   -- and the value of it is 1
where s.web_design = "1"                          -- where web_design = "1"
```